# Is there a way to use mongoDB in SSRS?

Tags: c#, mongodb, reporting-services

I have SSRS set up to use for reports and i also will need to support mongoDB and was wondering if anyone knows of a way to accomplish this? I have looked and have not seen a solid answer to this as of yet. Thank you for any input.

Comment: http://cdn.cdata.com/help/DGA/ado/pg_ssrsreportdesigner.htm

Comment: Thanks! i appreciate the info.

Answer (score 1):

Well. Yes you can do this using an ODBC connections for mongodb BI(mongosqld) using port number 3307 as default. You may change your port number using a configuration file as well. Then open SSRS and add data source using ODBC connections. Then create data sets using your required query.
If you require any more information please let me know.
Thanks.